# HTTP2 Will make bundling process obsolete?

Tags: http, bundling-and-minification, http2

I understand that HTTP2 connection will allow file transfer between server and client to happen in a single connection.

In http world, file transfer will happen in separate connection, and this is a performance matter, hence files will be bundled and sent to client in a single connection so that server / client dont have to maintain multiple connection.

Does this mean in HTTP2, bundling wont be necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing File Cacheing and HTTP2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588692/optimizing-file-cacheing-and-http2)

Comment: Yes. it is.. thanks.. do i have to remove the question ?