# Does my hosting use hHTTPS2?

Tags: http2

This webpage: https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test Tells me that my hosting supports HTTPS2 - but is it using it? And if so then should I change my combined JavaScript files to individual ones? Or is browser support "not quite there" yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to use this browser (chrome ) plugin

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin
```

OR you can check it also with your chrome dev tools .. under the network tab the protocol cell display to you if it is in http1 or http2 ... if you don't see the protocol cell do a right click on the newtork tab and choose the prootcol voice...

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you - the protocol shown is "h2" - presumably that refers to HTTP2? EDIT - n/m the plugin says it is

Comment: As a follow up - what do you think is a good way to measure when you should "uncombine" JS files (since combining is anti-pattern with http2)? (spriting and concatenation are the two that I'm concerned with)

Comment: See here for my thoughts in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588692/optimizing-file-cacheing-and-http2